# AdView Constructor issue in Adapter

Tags: android, admob, adview

I get the error below when I try to initialize an Ad

> AdView (Context, android.util.AttributeSet)
>   in AdView cannot be applied to
>   (Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize).

Here is my code

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private static final int EMPTY_VIEW = 1;
private static final int DATA_VIEW = 2;
private static final int AD_VIEW = 3;
public List<Note> allnotes;

public NotesAdapter(List<Note> allnotes, Context context) {
    this.allnotes = allnotes;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
    if (viewType == EMPTY_VIEW) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.note_zero, parent, false);
        holder = new emptyViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType ==AD_VIEW) {
        view = new AdView(context, AdSize.BANNER);
    } else {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_note_card, parent, false);
        holder = new myViewHolder(view);
    }
    return  holder;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no AdView constructor with AdSize. Use that:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(context);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
```

Comment: The "this" context isnt available in an adapter. only in an activity. Thats my error

Comment: Answer edited. The context field from NotesAdapter you set in NotesAdapter constructor should be availble. Use AdView adView = new AdView(context);

Comment: I already used the context i passed in my constructor but the error persists, thats why i got stuck, but thanks though

Comment: The error occurs because you put AdSize.BANNER into constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

> new AdView(context, AdSize.BANNER)

you are using `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize` and the method needs `android.util.AttributeSet`. Try this out:

```
mAdView = new AdView(context);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId("myAdUnitId");
```

*For future reference:*

Apparently, the API has been updated and now the available constructors are:

> AdView(Context context)
>      Construct an AdView from code.
>   AdView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
>      Construct an AdView from an XML layout.
>   AdView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
>      Construct an AdView from an XML layout.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, I have looked at the API, use the second option. For reference of all constructors, see [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView).